# function nil.email/0 is undefined or private in elixir phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to know why am I getting this error and how to fix. Could it be due to user id conflict in database? Another thing is this might not even be the file which is giving out this error.

[image]

```
defmodule MessengyrWeb.UserView do
  use MessengyrWeb, :view

  def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
    %{
        user: user_json(user)
    }
  end

  def user_json(user) do
    hash_email = :crypto.hash(:md5, user.email) |> Base.encode16 |> String.downcase
    avatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash_email}"

    %{
        id: user.id,
        username: user.username,
        avatarURL: avatar_url,
    }
  end
end
```

This is what I get after commenting out `id: user.id` and `user: user.username` and replacing `hash_email` with a static integer.

[image]

```
def user_json(user) do
    hash_email = 123
    avatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash_email}"

    %{
        # id: user.id,
        # username: user.username,
        avatarURL: avatar_url,
    }
end
```

Comment: Your `user` variable has a `nil` instead of a user struct. We would have to see how you are retrieving the user to tell you why this is happening. But chances are you are calling `Attendance.Repo.get` with an id that does not exist.

Comment: I got it. Thanks! @JustinWood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the whole database and run `mix ecto.create && mix ecto.migrate`again.

And `mix phx.server` and created a new user account.

Also tested with **a different browser** it works. So I **cleared cookies** of the former browser and it works now.

Comment: do `mix ecto.reset` to delete and reset database

Answer (score 0):

I did `mix ecto.reset` and it worked for me.

Comment: seems more of a comment